# JavaScript: Detect Alt/Option Key on Select Element

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, event-handling, alt-key

I am running this on a Macintosh, hence the `option` key.

I have a simple menu in HTML as follows:

```
<select name="select-item">
    <option value="">Test</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
```

It is inside a `form` element which, in JavaScript has the creatively named `form` variable.

How can I tell whether the option/alt key is down when a menu item is selected?

I have tried the following code:

```
form['select-item'].onchange=function(e) {
    alert(e.altKey);
}
```

but I get `undefined` as the result, regardless of whether the option key is down or not. The same applies if I try the `shift` key instead.

No jQuery, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the keydown event on window and storing the values

```
var keys = [];
window.onkeyup = function(e) {keys[e.keyCode]=false;}
window.onkeydown = function(e) {keys[e.keyCode]=true;}


form['select-item'].onchange=function(e) {
    alert(keys[18]);  // 18 is the keyCode for alt
}
```

You can find all keycodes on https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tillxy/55d6s86r/) is a jsfiddle demo

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how _can_ I detect the key on change?

Comment: Okay, sorry for missunderstanding you. I hope the edit on my answer will fix your problem c: